# Всем привет! Подскажите как изменить цвет fieldset при отправки формы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтобы при пустом input, вложенном в fieldset, fieldset менял цвет своего border при отправки формы. Как это можно реализовать?

```js
const form = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
const formInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input')


formInputs.forEach(
  addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.previousElementSibling.classList.add('select');
  }),
);
```

```css
.select {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <fieldset class="field">
    <legend>Text</legend>
    <input type="text" class='input' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> чтобы при пустом input, вложенном в fieldset, fieldset менял цвет своего border при отправки формы. Как это можно реализовать?

Например так...

```js
const form = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
const field = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.input')

form.forEach(o => {
  o.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input.forEach(function(e) {
      if (e.value === '') {
        e.parentNode.classList.add('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.input:focus + legend {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <fieldset class="field">
    <input type="text" class='input' />
    <legend>Text</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а не подскажешь  если в этом fieldset есть еще один элемент помимо input, как при клике на input к этому элементу добавить класс?

Comment: @user524692, так ты можешь отредактировать свой вопрос... Покажи в нем что за элемент... На пальца не особо можно объяснить.

Comment: Отредактировал, мне нужно чтобы при клике на input, legend менял свой цвет.

Comment: @user524692, что потом? `legend` так и будет потом оставаться таким цветом?

Comment: пока input в фокусе, после фокуса возвращается назад

Comment: Если переставить элементы - можно решить простым `css`... Смотри мой вариант, я дополнил его.

Comment: спасибо еще раз